# Gas Flow Between Two Pressure Vessels

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

I am trying to determine the volumetric flow rate between two pressure vessels at different pressures and volumes.  Nitrogen gas is stored in a K bottle at 2640 psi (P1)and 3045 in$^3$ (V1).  The tank being filled is stored at 14.7 psi (P2) and 16,000 in$^3$ (V2).  The connection between them can have a cross section area $A$.

I know at the very beginning of the system the flow rate will be high and will decrease as the pressure reaches equilibrium.  Also, V2 will need to have a pressure increase of 10-100 psi/sec and at 2180 psi the volume expands by 570 in$^3$.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing to realize is, if the flow is turbulent, what most likely would be. In such a case,calculation of the flow would be very difficult. For laminar flows, like via tubing of small diameter and long length, there is the formula for the flow. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation.  $$\Delta p=\frac{8 \eta LQ}{\pi R^4}$$

Comment: The flow will be turbulent, and will be limited to sonic velocity at the smallest cross-section that the flow encounters.  Obviously, mass flow decreases as pressure decreases, so a clever integral would be required, and you can expect a logarithmic form to result, because mass flow rate is proportional to pressure.